# How to copy files to external hard drive in php

Tags: php, macos

I'm using a php script to download large files from a server and then do some processing. How can I copy them to my external hard drive after I'm done processing them?

**Update:**
I can use `copy()`. How do I reference my external drive? It shows up as Iomega_HDD in finder. But

```
copy('test.jpg, 'Iomega_HDD/test2.jpg')
```

doesn't work.

**Update2:**

```
copy('test.jpg, '/Volumes/Iomega_HDD/test2.jpg')
```

Did trick ...

Comment: if the hardrive is mounted you can just copy the files to the appropriate directory by specifying the file path.

Comment: I have a few thousand files and would like to automate it ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use any file function and specify the full path to the correct drive, assuming you have write access to that drive. Here is an example using `file_put_contents`.

In windows:

```
file_put_contents( 'E:\somefile.txt', $data);
```

In Linux:

```
file_put_contents( '/media/{yourdeviceID}/somefile.txt', $data);
```

Comment: he already has files, so you think he should convert them in to a string in memory and write them out again vs plain old copy?

Comment: Hence the phrases: "Just use any file function" and "Here is an example using {function name}".

Comment: thanks. I can use copy(). How do I reference my external drive? It shows up as Iomega_HDD in finder. copy('test.jpg, 'Iomega_HDD/test2.jpg') doesn't work

Comment: Add it to your question, will help visibility.

Comment: How can you make it if E: unit is on a PC client on the network?

Answer (score 2):

why not us the the php `copy()` command.